# How can i send message using my sim wirelessly through java code?

Tags: java, sms, jsmpp

Can anybody tell me how can i use my sim card wirelessly to send SMS to someone using java so that the billing procedure will be done through my sim card.

Comment: [Tethering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering). One word answers a thing now?

Comment: let me know the whole procedure.